# Parsing iwlist scan using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need run custom command in a wireless client cpe to get the  following data

ESSID, MAC, FREQUENCY,QUALITY,LEVEL, NOISE.

```
XM.v5.5.8# iwlist ath0 scanning
ath0      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: DC:9F:DB:08:49:DE
                    ESSID:"Satek"
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:5.54 GHz (Channel 108)
                    Quality=28/94  Signal level=-68 dBm  Noise level=-92 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Extra:bcn_int=100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:mtik_ie=dd2a000c42000000011e0014000000661a05000041502d43454e54524f2d35000000000000000000
```

I try with this code from other forum

```
XM.v5.5.8# iwlist ath0 scanning | awk -F '[ :=]+' '/(ESS|Freq|Qual)/{ printf $3" " } /Encr/{ print $4 }'
"Satek" 5.54 28/94 on
"Satek" 5.57 14/94 on
"Satek" 5.6 13/94 on
"Satek" 5.61 9/94 on
"Satek" 5.64 36/94 on
"Satek" 5.68 26/94 on
"Satek" 5.7 9/94 on
"IVICA" 5.825 17/94 on
```

Almost all what I need but I don't know how to get the other items like mac address signal level and noise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For parsing with such differences in the wanted value formats, you will either need an `awk script` or a `bash script` to give you the flexibility you need to get all the values. (you can do it in one line, but it gets very messy). Here is a bash script that will parse `iwlist` and output `mac essid frq chn qual lvl enc`. I have no `Noise`, but you can simply follow the format to add it if you desire.

The usage is from the command line as you want. E.g. `iwlist 'iface' scan | bash parseiwl.sh` (where '`iface'` is `ath0` for you and `parseiwl.sh` is just the name I saved the script under). **Note:** this script is non-portable due to the use of `[[]]` and `=~` so use in bash only:

```
#!/bin/bash

## print header lines
echo ""
echo " mac                 essid         frq   chn qual   lvl  enc"

while IFS= read -r line; do

    ## test line contenst and parse as required
    [[ "$line" =~ Address ]] && mac=${line##*ss: }
    [[ "$line" =~ \(Channel ]] && { chn=${line##*nel }; chn=${chn:0:$((${#chn}-1))}; }
    [[ "$line" =~ Frequen ]] && { frq=${line##*ncy:}; frq=${frq%% *}; }
    [[ "$line" =~ Quality ]] && { 
        qual=${line##*ity=}
        qual=${qual%% *}
        lvl=${line##*evel=}
        lvl=${lvl%% *}
    }
    [[ "$line" =~ Encrypt ]] && enc=${line##*key:}
    [[ "$line" =~ ESSID ]] && {
        essid=${line##*ID:}
        echo " $mac  $essid  $frq  $chn  $qual  $lvl  $enc"  # output after ESSID
    }

done
```

**example:**

```
sudo iwlist wlp23s0 scan | bash parseiwl.sh

mac                 essid         frq   chn qual   lvl  enc
00:14:D1:C6:C8:6F  "skyline_633"  2.442  7  54/70  -56  on
```

Comment: Nicely done! You might consider using printf with format strings containing width values (ie. `%20s`) to make sure everything lines up even when content lengths vary.

Comment: Yes, you are correct on `printf`. This was a bit of a **rapid prototype** as opposed to a finely formatted finished product. I had no idea what order or format the OP wants the final output in, so I just spaced until the output looked reasonable :)

Comment: What could be happen? `code`XM.v5.5.8# ls
dropbear_dss_host_key  nscan.sh
dropbear_rsa_host_key  parseiwl.sh
XM.v5.5.8# iwlist 'ath0' scan | bash parseiwl.sh
-sh: bash: not found
`code`

Comment: If you have copied the script and placed it in `parseiwl.sh` on your computer, then `iwlist 'ath0' scan | bash parseiwl.sh` is the correct command. If the error is `-sh: bash: not found` that doesn't make must sense. It seems to be saying that you have a stray `-sh` somewhere on a line by itself (or on a line separated by multiple `;`) that is being interpreted as a command (which bash says **not found**). Recheck your copy of the script and add the line `set -x` under the first line `#!/bin/bash` to output debugging info as your run the script. Also show output of `which bash`

Comment: Yes this device is a ubiquiti nanostation m5 only have one persistent directory in /etc/persisten I've uploaded the file and give it execute permisions with chmod a+x filename and then I've excecute the script with the command line tht you give me. Let me try the last advice .

Comment: same Issue I've added this `code`#!/bin/bash
set -x
## print header lines
echo ""
echo " mac                 essid         frq   chn qual   lvl  enc"

while IFS= read -r line; do`code`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. When you say `code` ... `code` are you saying that is what is printed to `stdout` or are you saying there is some error?

Comment: post the output of `which bash` and post the output of `( echo "hello world" | while read -r line; do echo "line -> $line"; done )`

Comment: I found this code in a forum  `code` iwlist ath0 scan | sed -ne 's#^[[:space:]]*\(Quality=\|Frequency:\|Encryption key:\|ESSID:\)#\1#p' -e 's#^[[:space:]]*\(Mode:.*\)$#\1\n#p'
 `code` but does't give me the mac address and I need it for lock ap to client. Im writing a windows app to avoid the credentials and device web settings use for the installers.

Comment: I looked and a `ubiquiti nanostation m5` is a wireless bridge. What version of Linux are you running and what version of bash? You can simply do `iwlist 'ath0' scan | grep Address | sed -e 's/^.*[:]\s//'` to get the mac address. The **bottom-line** is that if your `ubiquiti nanostation m5` will not run the script I posted, then it is not running a full version of bash. Being a bridge/router, I suspect it is running `sh` or Boerne-Shell **not** bash.

Comment: **You are not running bash. airOS 3.4** (up to current firmware release 5.4) is a firmware embedded OS [**AirOS 3.4**](http://wiki.ubnt.com/AirOS_3.4). Try running the script on bash -- it is fine. Your issue is you do not have bash. It is a complete guess what will work and what won't on the `ubiquiti nanostation m5` without knowing what shell you have.

Comment: WEll I'm working with what I get I able to filter the desired strings with a regex in the windows aplication after running the script.

Comment: thanks men, I put your name in the file!